# Copying objects between layers

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, layers, editing

I have a problem with copying objects between shapes in ArcMap 10.8. I do this:

- first I activate the editing of the layer where I want to paste,
- then I select the necessary objects in another layer,
- then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and that's it.
- The "Insert" button is disabled.

What am I doing wrong? It's interesting that "copy-paste" sometimes succeeds without problems. I can't figure out what this is about.

Comment: You **paste special** to copy geometries from one layer into another.

Comment: I recall from my old ArcMap days people having issues copying and pasting that turned out to be they had features selected in multiple layers or they were trying to do it in an unfocused layout view.